# Strange error while using Swift Package OpenSSL (code signing a Swift Package?)

Tags: swift, openssl, swift-package

I have added the Swift Package OpenSSL to my project.

When I run the app, it crashes with this error

```
/Users/myself/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-axyxgyhzyndlrqbybswlbgbcdcqd/Build/Products/Debug/OpenSSL.framework/Versions/A/OpenSSL' (code signature in <E5363788-58DE-301F-A80C-24FC78AD277E> '/Users/myself/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-axyxgyhzyndlrqbybswlbgbcdcqd/Build/Products/Debug/OpenSSL.framework/Versions/A/OpenSSL' not valid for use in process: mapping process and mapped file (non-platform) have different Team IDs), '/Users/myself/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-axyxgyhzyndlrqbybswlbgbcdcqd/Build/Products/Debug/PackageFrameworks/OpenSSL.framework/Versions/A/OpenSSL' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/OpenSSL.framework/Versions/A/OpenSSL' (no such file), '/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenSSL.framework/Versions/A/OpenSSL' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
```

The error mentions Team ID signing... signing a package? what?

The last lines of the error shows xcode searching for the library inside macOS? This is a package!

The package is here: https://github.com/KatkayApps/OpenSSL

Any ideas?

Comment: OpenSSL doesn’t usually come in a package, it is generally regarded that OpenSSL should be a static library. Something bigger is going on.

Comment: it is strange because OpenSSL is listed on the "add packages" feature.

Comment: Is it an OpenSSL library or a Package to `make` an OpenSSL  library there are plenty of those but you have to `make` the library itself. Look at the readme

Comment: see for yourself here: https://github.com/KatkayApps/OpenSSL

Comment: That is a package to `make` you can use the frameworks provided in the package (usually a bad idea) but your project doesn't use the package itself just one of the frameworks it provides

Comment: @Duck That appears to be based on the OpenSSL 1.1.1 branch, which EOLs **today**.

Comment: I have tried to make the static framework, by downloading OpenSSL from the original source and using make. Same error.